# Как выполнить фильтрацию объектов?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть фильтр на странице c разными параметрами, использую `gem 'ransack'`

controller

```
def index
   @search = Restaurant.search(params[:q])
   @restaurants = @search.result.where(:publish => true, :status => 1)
end
```

index

```
<%= search_form_for @search, id: 'catalog_filter' do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

1. Как можно фильтровать по рейтингу объекта? я использую `gem 'ratyrate'`
2. Как можно фильтровать по цене. Использую jquery ui?

   ```
   <div class="slider"></div>
   <%= f.search_field :check, id: 'hidden' %>

   $(".slider" ).slider({
       animate: true,
       range: "min",
       value: 970,
       min: 250,
       max: 2700,
       step: 1,
       slide: function( event, ui ) {
           $( "#slider-result" ).html( ui.value );
       },
       change: function(event, ui) {
           $('#hidden').attr('value', ui.value);

       }
   })
   ```

[image: фото]

Ruby 2.2
Rails 5.0

Answer (score 0):

```
 <%= f.search_field :check_lteq, id: 'hidden' %>
```

_lteq ищет все что `<=` заданного значения

```
#=> SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE (`products`.`price` <= 1000)
```

_gteq ищет все что `>=` заданного значения

```
# => "SELECT `items`.* FROM `items` WHERE `items`.`price` >= 1000)"
```

Comment: @D-side обновил ответ